# asynchronous threads each running an infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm implementing a program which contains different tasks and all have implemented Runnable. e.g. there is a task which works on a database and sends some of the tuples to a synchronized shared memory and subsequently, there is another thread which checks the shared memory and sends messages to a queue. Moreover, these two threads iterate over an infinite while loop.

Already, I have used the fixedThreadPool to execute these threads.

The problem is that sometimes program control remained in the first running thread and the second one never gets the chance to go to its running state.

Here is a similar sample code to mine:

```
public class A implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
        //do something
        }
    }
}
public class B implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
        //do something
        }
    }
}
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        A a = new A();
        executorService.execute(a);
        B b = new B();
        executorService.execute(b);
    }
}
```

I'd also done something tricky, make the first thread to sleep once for a second after a short period of running. As a result, it makes the second thread to find the chance for running. But is there any well-formed solution to this problem? where is the problem in your opinion?

Comment: Is Driver class Runnable because it overrides run method ?

Comment: Does the sample code exhibit the problem behavior yoy describe?

Comment: @niemar no, it was just a copy-paste mistake. changes added. thanks.

Comment: @mattfreake, yeah it causes the same behavior.

Comment: @epcpu How do you tell when the current loops don't do anything?

Comment: @mattfreake the second loop should publish it's output to Rabbitmq, but there would be no messages. Additionally, when I run the program in debug mode the second thread is blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good example of Producer/Consumer pattern. There are many ways of implementing this. Here's one naive implementation using `wait/notify` pattern.

```
public class A implements Runnable {
    private Queue<Integer> queue;
    private int maxSize;

    public A(Queue<Integer> queue, int maxSize) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                while (queue.size() == maxSize) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Queue is full, " + "Producer thread waiting for "
                                + "consumer to take something from queue");
                        queue.wait();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Random random = new Random();
                int i = random.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Producing value : " + i);
                queue.add(i);
                queue.notifyAll();
            }

        }
    }

}

public class B implements Runnable {
    private Queue<Integer> queue;

    public B(Queue<Integer> queue) {
        super();
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (queue) {
                while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty," + "Consumer thread is waiting"
                            + " for producer thread to put something in queue");
                    try {
                        queue.wait();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("Consuming value : " + queue.remove());
                queue.notifyAll();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And here's hot we set things up.

```
public class ProducerConsumerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> buffer = new LinkedList<>();
        int maxSize = 10;

        Thread producer = new Thread(new A(buffer, maxSize));
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new B(buffer));

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.submit(producer);
        executorService.submit(consumer);
    }

}
```

In this case the `Queue` acts as the shared memory. You may substitute it with any other data structure that suits your needs. The trick here is that you have to coordinate between threads carefully. That's what your implementation above lacks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may sound radical, but non-framework parts of asynchonous code base should try avoiding `while(true)` hand-coded loops and instead model it as a (potentially self-rescheduling) callback into an executor

This allows more fair resources utilization and most importantly per-iteration monitoring instrumentation.

When the code is not latency critical (or just while prototyping) the easiest way is to do it with `Executors` and possibly `CompletableFuture`s.

```
class Participant implements Runnable {
    final Executor context;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Item work = workSource.next();
        if (workSource.hasNext()) {
            context.execute(this::run);
        }
    }
}
```